# A program to allow the user to create a checklist

Tags: python

This is my coding so far

```
numofthings=int(input("How many things do you need to pack? "))
numoftasks=int(input("How many tasks do you need to complete to prepare? "))

checklist1=[]
end=' '
while end.lower()!='end':
    item=input("Please enter the things you need to pack and type 'End' when you're done: ")
    checklist1.append(item)
    end=item

checklist2=[]
end=' '
while end.lower()!='end':
    task=input("What tasks do you have to complete and type 'End' when you're done ")
    checklist2.append(task)
    end=task
print(checklist1)
print(checklist2)
```

How do I get the items they list saved into an array/list?
Also how do I make it so that they can only list the number of items that they said they had to pack?

I only started coding 2 weeks ago so sorry if it's obvious and I've overlooked it

Comment: What is your question? Is something not working how you expect it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get the items they list saved into an array/list?

You're already doing that just fine: that's what you get with

```
checklist.append(item)
```

If you stick a simple reporting statement in your loop, you'll see that happening as you go:

```
checklist.append(item)
print(checklist)
```

Comment that line before you turn in the program.

I suspect that you need two separate check-lists, though: one each for packing and tasks.

> How do I make it so that they can only list the number of items that
>   they said they had to pack?

Decide how you plan to decide when you have enough.  Your current code looks for the trigger value "end".  If you know how many times you have to iterate *before* you enter the loop, then use a **for** loop:

```
for i in range(num_of_things):
```

Does that get you moving?